# jquery datepicker ui first enabled date as default date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an inline jquery ui datepicker that has some days disabled, like this

```
$('.calendar').datepicker({
    defaultDate: '',
    beforeShowDay: function (date){
        return [is_valid(date),''];
    }
});
```

Sometimes the current date can be a disabled date. In this case I would like to automatically make the next enabled date to be the default date..

What would be the easiest way to do this?

---

For testing, here's a function that will always make the current date disabled

```
function is_valid(date) {
    var current = new Date();
    return date.getDate() - 2 > current.getDate();
}
```

I also created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/crBab/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution

```
function get_default_date() {
    var date = new Date();
    while(!is_valid(date)) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    }
    return date;
}

$('.calendar').datepicker({
    defaultDate: get_default_date(),
    beforeShowDay: function (date){
        return [is_valid(date),''];
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crBab/5/